# Sum the integers an int gets in c#

Tags: c#, class, integer

OK the the title is very confusing I know, so let me explain the problem.

I have a class let's call him A

*important note this is a sample code.

class1.cs

```
public int Test(int i)
{
   return i
}
```

in Form1.cs i do this

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    Class1 A = new Class1();
    Class1 B = new Class1();

    A.Test(a);
    B.Test(b);
  }
```

so what i want to do is sum the variables.
you can do this by doing this:

```
 int c = A.Test(a) + B.Test(b);
```

but i want to do this in a class. How should i do this?

EDIT

OK some more info

this is a school project and the teacher wants it like this:

he said: "it's really annoying that if you do it this way

```
int c = A.Test(a) + B.Test(b);
```

you constantly have to add extra code, when you call your class again, if I add a extra variable I also have to add that in the sum.

*example

```
int c = 2;

Class1 C = new Class();

C.Test(c);

int c = A.Test(a) + B.Test(b) + C.Test(c);
```

If you have to make a hundred variables you also must add them to the sum, that is annoying and make's your code too long. So you must make a method to automatically sums up all the ints, oh and this method must be in a class and this class is not allowed to be static."

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: You've presented pseudo-code rather than real code, suggesting you haven't put enough effort into making sure that your question is as clear as it can be - you've shown a *method* called `A`, but then tried to use a constructor accepting an int, then a `Test` method you haven't shown us. It's all *very* unclear. Please take a step back and take the time to write a good question. Read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on what you need? do you need a function/method with in a class to sum two integers? if yes, let  me know that is straightforward i will give you the code.

Comment: Are you looking for a class that takes a collection/array of 'Test' and then performs a sum?

Comment: Why are you passing an int to `Test` just to return the same int? `Test(int a, int b) { return a + b; }` will return the sum of two numbers

Comment: You need to go and search on the internet, you should be able to find examples and you will gain knowledge from doing so. Just asking someone to do it for you won't teach you anything... Try some things, show us what problems you hit and what you are not understanding.

Comment: Do you maybe want a method `Add(int n)` that adds to the previous total (and possibly returns that new total), where you use a single class instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to do your homework for you because you will not learn from it.

```
public int AddAll(params int[] input){
    int total = 0; 
    foreach (int i in input){ //loop through all the inputs
        total += i; //same as total = total + i
    }
    return total;
}
```

This code will allow you to have multiple inputs without knowing exactly how many, you can call it by using:

```
AddAll(1,2,3,4,5)
```